# matlab: interface for selecting points on plot by clicking

Tags: matlab, user-interface, click, point

I have a `2XN` vector of points. I'd like to plot it and then enable the user to select one of the points by clicking on that point. I guess I can do it by myself by getting the mouse coordinates and select the point closest to them etc. I am wondering whether matlab provides a plug-and-play method for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to accomplish this, as far as I know.
You can do one of the following:

1. Check the distance and select the closest point (As you said yourself)
2. Call the plot command `N` times, and assign a different callback for each plot.

In this case you create the graphics in the following way:

```
   for i=1:N 
      plot( X(i),Y(i), 'o', 'ButtonDownFcn', @(x)CallBack(x,i));
   end
```

And the callbacks look like that:

```
   function CallBack(x,i)
       fprintf(1,'A callback on P[%d] was called');
   end
```

---

If you want a special case of `2xN` points: a draggable polygon, you can use the `impoly` command instead.